# Pass variables to mongodb query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can I pass a variable to a query so:

```
db.collection('coll').find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) throw err;
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        var Id = parseInt(doc._id); // a returnd _id from previous query
        Id--;
        query = {_id : parseInt(doc._id) }; // returns null
        // OR query = {_id : Id }; // error
        db.collection('coll').find(query).toArray(function(err, beforeDocs) {
            //if (err) throw err;
            console.dir(beforeDocs);
        });
});
```

In fact what I am trying to do is query by id to get the record that comes before the results given in the first query

Any ideas??

Is it at all possible to query mongodb with variables??

`var query = { _id : var i, name : var name , etc...}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search for the document that shows up before a match in a mongodb query.

I believe your best bet is something like this:

```
var prevDoc = null;  // to store the previous document
var cursor = db.collection('collection').find({}); // get all docs
cursor.sort('_id', 1); // it only makes sense to grab previous if they're sorted
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
  if(err) throw err;
  if(doc == null) { // if we reached the end of our cursor...
    db.close();     // close the db connection
  } else {
    if( doc.foo === "bar" ) { // here you put your match criteria
      console.dir(prevDoc); // here you print your previous document
    }
  }
  prevDoc = doc; // store current doc so that it's available for next iteration
});
```

To answer your direct question ("Is it at all possible to query mongodb with variables?"), it is possible to query mongodb with a query which contains variables that already have values at the time the query is created. It is not possible, however, to pass new uninstantiated variables along for mongodb to manipulate somehow.

Comment: sorry but I think you misunderstood me or I explained poorly: the code does work, the issue is with string literals. I wish to do a WHERE clause with a variable, not a literal! !("bar") but --> === var. does that explain better?? in the example I gave it is the query with var Id

Comment: You have explained that you are trying to find the document that comes before some document which matches some search criteria. The `if` clause that I provided is an *example for search criteria*. If you have a variable (`objId`) that contains the value of some document's `_id` and you want to find the document before that document, then you can change the `if` condition to `if( doc._id === objId ) {`.